# Unable to click on a Button which is inside a Form(Its says element with locator is not visible)

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor, ui-automation, webautomation

I wanted to select a button in a Frame ..
But some how its not selecting .. Tried below code to switch to frame and click on element in Protractor with TypeScript ..

```
await browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.xpath("//div[@id='main-container']")).getWebElement()); 
await this.element(by.css('.uploadDiv #uploadP')).click(); --> Did not work

let frame3 = element(by.xpath("//div[@id='main-container']")).getWebElement();
        browser.switchTo().frame(frame3); 
await this.element(by.css('.uploadDiv #uploadP')).click(); --> Did not work
```

[See the HTML of it in given screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke6L4.png)

Comment: Added the Elements image above

Answer (score 0):

you can print the element rectangle or get innerhtml to see whether the element is hidden.

an easier way is to leverage some recorder tools such as vistual studio code clicknium extension to recorde the element and then do validation, it will highlight the target element position